# N total posts awaiting review, but why does clicking on it show nothing for review?

Tags: discussion

In the topbar, I see "N total posts awaiting review", but clicking on it shows nothing for review: all items (low quality post, first post, etc) have zero.  I had already done a review, but why is the number still more than 0?

For example, N is currently 8 for me.  But in this session, I didn't skip 8 review items.

Comment: It could be that there are items in the queue that you already reviewed but needs review of other community members, too.

Comment: check this: http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/230802/226837

Comment: Upvoted, thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sometimes posts are in multiple queues, e.g. First post and VLQ. When you skip them in one queue, they get skipped in all queues, that way you can have a bigger number showing up there without actually having skipped that many posts.

Comment: Do you routinely see "N total posts awaiting review" with N>0?  One has to click on it to actually see if there's something for review?

Comment: I just tried on Bitcoin.SE: I've skipped one, now I have 7 shown on the review queues but I have 9 showing up in my topbar. Maybe the topbar doesn't refresh as quickly as the review queues do.

Comment: So, the answer is "yes", that does happen every once in a while when I've skipped an item from the queues.

Answer (score 3):

Your answer is [caching](http://shouldiblamecaching.net).

Additionally, skipping items removes them from your queues but not the topbar count, and there may be some items you can't review in the first place.

Comment: If there are items we can't review in the first place, is the site going to fix it so that it isn't even included in the topbar count?